# PDF Table Text Extraction

Tags: pdf, text-extraction, coordinate-transformation

I know that Table Text Extraction not everyone's cup of tea. But while reading PDF Stream data about table, there are certain things that I don't understand.

The PDF Code Stream of Table is:

```
q                                    % Graphic State Starting Point

0 292.5 595.3 442.8 re               % Rectangle x y Width Height
W*                                   % Clipping Even Odd Rule
n                                    % End without Filling

0 0 0 rg                             % Color of Stroke
161 735 m                            % Move to New Path
160.8 734.7 l  89.3 734.7 l 89 735 l  88.8 735.3 l 161.3 735.3 l
161 735 l                            % straight line
h                                    % Close the Current Path
f*                                   % Fill Path with Even Odd Rule
Q
```

And Underline is:

```
q                                 % Graphic State Starting Point
1 0 0 1 451.5 759.5 cm            % Current matrix
0.5 w                             % Width of Stroke
0 0 0 RG                          % color
0 -0.8 m                          % Move to New Path
72 -0.8 l                         % Straight Line
S                                 % Stroke Line
Q                                 % End of Graphic State
```

In underline the `m` modifies the `cm` and sets that to 451.5 759.5 and straight line is drawn from current point i.e. 451.5 to 72 points i.e 493.5 which is less that 0.8 to `cm`, i.e 759.5

I don't understand now, how the table line would be drawn from which point to which point.

Comment: Why are you mixing horizontal and vertical movements in your question? Basically you are stating that some x movement is not equal to some other y movement.

Comment: @Jongware I don't understand what you want to say?

Comment: That's a series of overlapping long flat rectangles. Y only varies from 734.7 to 735.3. Will appear visually as a line

Comment: @dwarring But how do you come to that conclusion

Answer (score 2):

Consider the line drawing section, where `m` is the move to operator and `l` is line-to:

```
               % command   coordinates
               % =====================              
161 735 m      % Move-to   a(161, 735)
160.8 734.7 l  % line-to   b(161, 735 -.3)
89.3  734.7 l  % line-to   c(90,  735 -.3)
89    735   l  % line-to   d(90,  735)
88.8  735.3 l  % line-to   e(90,  735 +.3)
161.3 735.3 l  % line to   f(161, 735 +.3)
161   735   l  % line to   g(161, 735)
h              % close-path
f              % fill
```

(There's some strange minor variations in `x` around 160 and 89 which are too small to register visually - rendering quirks?).

[Under very high resolution line will have arrows at end

```
<============ ...   =======>
```

]

Other than that it's drawing a very thin long box with corners `(89, 734,7)`, `(161, 734.7)`,  `(161, 735.3)`, and `(89, 735.3)`. The affect of the +/- ).3 points on the y-axis is most likely to give the effect of a slightly thickened line rather than a rectangle.